# Sliding balls and stars on a 4x4 grid

Tags: visual, strategy, reachability

You are playing a game on the following 4x4 grid. It contains balls, stars, empty cells, walls (solid blue squares) and target cells (T). Each turn you can slide **all** the balls and **all** the stars into one of four directions: left, up, right or down. An object will continue sliding along a direction until it hits another object (including walls) or the boundary of the grid. Walls do not move. Can you get the balls to finish on the target cells?

[image]

Comment: We now have stars, which move just like the balls, but kind of get in the way. I think this one is quite hard, but I was wrong in the past about these puzzles. Once I have some more time I will hopefully make a mobile game from these puzzles.

Comment: Do the balls stop when they hit a target? And the T at 3 , 2 does not have any type of support, so is it just a diversion from the other one?

Comment: The balls slide through the targets unless there is something to block them on the other side.

Comment: Check out my earlier puzzles on this theme to get a better idea.

Comment: This is my 300th puzzle here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence needed to put the balls in their place is:

> LURULURDLDRDLURDRULDLURULURDLDRDLULD

I don't have any fancy animation thingy to show my result, but after checking several times on my notebook, I believe it's correct.

Thought process:

> To get the balls into position, having all three stars below the balls was needed. To do so, switching the balls from a horizontal position (both on the same row for most of the moves) to a horizontal one (both on the same column for most moves), or separating them altogether, to then slowly pass the stars on the lower part of the puzzle, while the balls take their place in the upper part.

Comment: Cool. How did you come up with that?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Best I can do is provide my [horribles notes](https://i.imgur.com/lpRAEmQ.jpg), but it was mostly trial and error. Along with a lot of thinking.

Comment: Kudos to your efforts! I thought the same logic, but gave up after 10 moves 